# Python 3.6: Signature of {method} incompatible with super type {Class}

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

While trying to update my code to be PEP-484 compliant (I'm using `mypy` 0.610) I've ran into the following report:

`$ mypy mymodule --strict-optional --ignore-missing-imports --disallow-untyped-calls --python-version 3.6`

`myfile.py:154: error: Signature of "deliver" incompatible with supertype "MyClass"`

MyClass:

```
from abc import abstractmethod

from typing import Any


class MyClass(object):

    @abstractmethod
    def deliver(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> bool:
        raise NotImplementedError
```

myfile.py:

```
class MyImplementation(MyClass):

[...]

    def deliver(self, source_path: str,
                dest_branches: list,
                commit_msg: str = None,
                exclude_files: list = None) -> bool:

        [...]

        return True
```

I'm definitely doing something wrong here, but I can't quite understand what :)

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: You **DO NOT** need to derive your class from `ABC` or add `@abstractmethod` decorators! The only purpose of that decorator is to "FORCE subclasses of your class to provide custom implementations of those methods". Python ALREADY allows ANY subclass to override the signatures of parent classes! **The rule is simple: The subclass method must accept being called exactly like the superclass.** So the error in your code is that you added EXTRA "required" arguments WITHOUT default values. **The real fix:** Add default values to new arguments, and match superclass signature's argument order!

Comment: Furthermore, since your superclass uses `**kwargs`, your subclass should have a trailing `**kwargs` at the end too, to catch any "loose/extra arguments". Otherwise it will still not be compatible with the superclass method signature. You can use the MyPy type checker to tell you whether your subclass signature is incompatible.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
@abstractmethod
def deliver(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> bool:
    raise NotImplementedError
```

This declaration doesn't mean subclasses can give `deliver` any signature they want. Subclass `deliver` methods must be ready to accept any arguments the superclass `deliver` method would accept, so your subclass `deliver` has to be ready to accept arbitrary positional or keyword arguments:

```
# omitting annotations
def deliver(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Your subclass's `deliver` does not have that signature.

---

If all subclasses are supposed to have the same `deliver` signature you've written for `MyImplementation`, then you should give `MyClass.deliver` the same signature too. If your subclasses are going to have different `deliver` signatures, maybe this method shouldn't really be in the superclass, or maybe you need to rethink your class hierarchy, or give them the same signature.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!, really appreciate it :). This makes total sense. I think my error was to think that `*args, **kwargs` would give me total freedom to implement any signature I want for that method on child objects. Then, my follow up question would be if it's a bad practice to follow the same signature as the superclass and then comment (annotate maybe?) the expected params for that implementation.

Comment: @Pawel: I would definitely consider that bad practice.

Comment: Yeah, again, it makes sense. And I don't want to work out of the boundaries of PEP-484, but at the same time I think (for my scenario, at least) each subclass should implement the `deliver` method the way they want. I guess some rethinking needs to be put in place :)

Comment: As far as I can see, this signature would accept any arguments that the superclass method accepts: `def deliver(self, source_path: str, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> bool:`. mypy still complains that he signature is incompatible.

Comment: @SeppoEnarvi: The superclass signature accepts any combination of arguments whatsoever. Your signature requires a `source_path` argument.

Comment: @Pawel: Did you get around to knowing how to rewrite this type of superclass and subclass? In a way that can show the relationship of the superclass and subclass & subclass method `deliver` could have a different signature.

Comment: @Pawel You **DO NOT** need to derive your class from `ABC` or add `@abstractmethod` decorators! The only purpose of that decorator is to "FORCE subclasses of your class to provide custom implementations of those methods". Python ALREADY allows ANY subclass to override the signatures of parent classes! **The rule is simple: The subclass method must accept being called exactly like the superclass.** So the error in your code is that you added EXTRA "required" arguments WITHOUT default values. **The real fix:** Add default values to new arguments, and match superclass signature's argument order!

Answer (score -2):

You can solve the question by using `Callable[..., Any]` and `type: ignore` such like bellow.

```py
from typing import Callable

class MyClass(object):
    deliver: Callable[..., bool]
    @abstractmethod
    def deliver(self, *args, **kwargs): # type: ignore
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get "Name "deliver" already defined on line 4"

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you should work it around this way:

1. Define abstract method without arguments:

   ```
   class MyClass:
       @abstractmethod
       def deliver(self) -> bool:
           raise NotImplementedError
   ```
2. In implementations get all your data from `self`:

   ```
   class MyImplementation(MyClass):
       def __init__(
               self,
               source_path: str,
               dest_branches: list,
               commit_msg: str = None,
               exclude_files: list = None
       ) -> None:
           super().__init__()
           self.source_path = source_path
           self.dest_branches = dest_branches
           self.commit_msg = commit_msg
           self.exclude_files = exclude_files

       def deliver(self) -> bool:
           # some logic
           if self.source_path and self.commit_msg:
               return True
           return False
   ```

This way you will have completely compatible method declarations and still can implement methods as you want.