# python typing abstractmethod with default arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I'm a little confuse how I'm supposed to type a base class abstract method?

In this case my base class only requires that the inheriting class implements a method named 'learn' that returns None without mandating any arguments.

```
class MyBaseClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def learn(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
       raise NotImplementedError()
```

but if I implement it
mypy raise en error 'Signature of "learn" incompatible with supertype "MyBaseClass"'

```
class MyOtherClass(MyBaseClass):
    def learn(self, alpha=0.0, beta=1) -> None:
       # do something
       return None
```

So how should I declare the learn method in the base class?

Comment: Note that ``*args, **kwargs`` doesn't mean "without mandating any arguments" but "accepting all arguments". For example, ``MyBaseClass.learn`` accepts a parameter ``gamma``. ``MyOtherClass`` does not, so it breaks the substitution principle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3.6: Signature of {method} incompatible with super type {Class}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003146/python-3-6-signature-of-method-incompatible-with-super-type-class)

Comment: 'joel first solution still has mypy "incompatible with supertype"' I cannot reproduce that. [MyPy accepts the subtyping, it only complains about the missing parameter types](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=3acc6463fe2a327095e3ae9033268279).

Comment: joel first solution works!

Comment: @MisterMiyagi sure is similar. Might be worth keeping since here we've only got parameters with default values, unlike in that qu.

Comment: @Gavello do you want to mark the solution as accepted if it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, I'd ask why you want a method without known arguments. That sounds like a design problem.

**One solution**

It's fine to add new parameters to subclasses if those parameters have default values (and the base class doesn't use `**kwargs`), like

```
class MyBaseClass:
    @abstractmethod
    def learn(self) -> None:
       raise NotImplementedError()

class MyOtherClass(MyBaseClass):
    def learn(self, alpha=0.0, beta=1) -> None:
       ...
```

though you won't be able to specify `alpha` and `beta` if you only know it's a `MyBaseClass`:

```
def foo(x: MyOtherClass) -> None:
    x.learn(alpha=3)  # ok

def foo(x: MyBaseClass) -> None:
    x.learn(alpha=3)  # not ok
```

**Why didn't `*args, **kwargs` work?**

If you have

```
class MyBaseClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def learn(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
       raise NotImplementedError()
```

then consider the function

```
def foo(x: MyBaseClass) -> None:
    ...
```

In that function, you can pass anything to `x.learn`, for example `x.learn(1, fish='three')`. This has to be true for any `x`. Since `x` can be an instance of a subclass of `MyBaseClass` (such as `MyOtherClass`), that subclass must also be able to accept those arguments.

Comment: I think *args, **kwargs will work but mypy complains

Comment: @Gavello [works fine for me](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=890574da4f018d73d9395b76867379e1). I'm confident *args, **kwargs won't work for the reasons I say above