# Python typing: Signature of "..." incompatible with supertype "..." with kwags

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I am trying to add typehints to some methods I want to overide from a library (in my case djangos `save()` method).

For this, I would like to use `**kwargs` in my implementation, because I am not concered about most of the arguments.

I have a minimal example here:

```
from typing import Any


class Abstract(object):
    def save(self, arg_1: bool = True, arg_2: bool = False, arg_3: bool = True) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError

class Implementation(Abstract):
    def save(self, arg_1: bool = True, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        # do something with arg_1
        super().save(arg_1=arg_1, **kwargs)
```

Running `mypy 0.942` here gives me:

```
error: Signature of "save" incompatible with supertype "Abstract"
note:      Superclass:
note:          def save(self, arg_1: bool = ..., arg_2: bool = ..., arg_3: bool = ...) -> None
note:      Subclass:
note:          def save(self, arg_1: bool = ..., **kwargs: Any) -> None
```

Do I really need to add all the arguments from the library to my implementation?

I mean technically, the Subclass still supports `arg_2` and `arg_3` through the `**kwargs`. So I am not getting why it should be incompatible.

Similar question (but a bit different): [Python 3.6: Signature of {method} incompatible with super type {Class}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003146/python-3-6-signature-of-method-incompatible-with-super-type-class)

Comment: what happens if I call `Implementation().save(True, True)`?

Comment: Thanks @joel. Thanks to the explanation of rogdham I understood your comment now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Developping on @joel 's comments.*

The `Abstract.save` method accepts 3 parameters, that can be both positional/keyword arguments. In other words, you could call `save(False, False, False)` or `save(arg_1=False, arg2=False, arg3=False)`.

Meanwhile, the `Implementation.save` method only one positional/keyword argument, plus any number of keyword-only arguments.

This means that the `Implementation.save` method is not just more generic than `Abstract.save`: you can **not** call `save(False, False, False)` on the implementation one.

To solve this, you could do something like the following, which allows flexibility while maintaining type compatibility:

```py
class Implementation(Abstract):
    def save(self, arg_1: bool = True, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        # do something with arg_1
        super().save(arg_1, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hello @rogdham,
Yes, that's it. Adding the `*args` makes mypy not complain anymore. Thanks. However, I think your explanation contains a mistake. I think it should be " you can not call `save(False, False, False)` on the implementation one.".

If you agree, please correct your answer. Then I will accept it as the right one.